# Will multiple NodeJS apps run on different cores?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a server with 2 CPU cores, then I launch 2 NodeJS apps. Since NodeJS is single-threaded, will those two nodeJS apps run on different cores or will they run on the same core?

For further information, I'd like to scale up my Socket.IO server. So I want to run two instances of this Socket.IO server **without clustering**. I worried even if I launched two instances of them it won't utilize all the cores.

Comment: Run it with pm2 or fork

Comment: @michalpavlik That's really unnecessary for most applications.  And, with only two cores, I really doubt this person is going to need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will those two nodeJS apps run on different cores or will they run on the same core?

You're running two different processes.  Scheduling where they run is up to your operating system.  Yes, they'll use different cores.  It's no different than multiple instances of any other executable.

> Since NodeJS is single-threaded...

This is a bit of a myth, and not applicable for most Node.js applications.  Your JavaScript runs single-threaded, sure, but all of the I/O and everything in the native modules can be multithreaded.

You can test this yourself easily, to get an idea for what the load looks like for your specific application.  It all depends on what you're doing, specifically.

Comment: So is it still possible for the OS to decide to run the two processes on the same core? And once the OS decided to run both on the same core, will it somehow change the core if it's overloaded? Sorry I think the question is more relevant to operating system stuffs, but perhaps you know the answer.

Comment: Ah NVM, I think I found the answer already: stackoverflow.com/questions/18496888/does-a-thread-run-on-the-same-cpu-core-throughout-its-life